# MQTT broker not connecting after internet disconnect and reconnect in Android 10

Tags: android, mqtt, iot, android-10.0

In my application i connect to IOT Device at that internet got disconnect and connection with MQTT Broker also disconnect then i send wifi to my IOT Device through TCP client and closing the socket i reconnect my internet connection after internet is connected again when i hit to re-establish connection with MQTT broker i got this ERROR:

```
MqttException (0) - java.net.SocketException: socket failed: ENONET (Machine is not on the network)
```

```
 private fun initMQTTConnector() {
        clientID = Installation.id(context)
        client = MqttAndroidClient(
            context, String.format(
                "%s:%s",
                BuildConfig.mqtt_server_url,
                BuildConfig.mqtt_server_port
            ),
            clientID, MemoryPersistence()
        )

        client!!.setCallback(listener)
        Timber.e(
            "qq - " + String.format(
                "%s:%s",
                BuildConfig.mqtt_server_url, //"tcp://192.168.1.164"
                BuildConfig.mqtt_server_port
            ) + " -- " + clientID
        )

            
        connectToMQTTServer()
    }


    fun connectToMQTTServer() {
        try {
            if(client == null){
                Timber.e("qq - client")
                initMQTTConnector()
            }else{
                Timber.e("qq - Retrying the MQTT connection...!")
                val options = MqttConnectOptions()
                options.setCleanSession(false) // change for mqtt connection issue
                options.setAutomaticReconnect(true)
                options.userName = BuildConfig.mqtt_server_user_name
                options.password = BuildConfig.mqtt_server_password.toCharArray()
                options.setKeepAliveInterval(90) //seconds

                token = client!!.connect(options)

                eventBusManager?.post(
                    EventBusManager.MessageEvent(
                        EventBusConstants.MQTT_CONNECTING
                    )
                )

                token?.actionCallback = object : IMqttActionListener {
                    override fun onSuccess(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken) {
                        // We are connected
                        Timber.e("qq - onSuccess for connection :: token.actionCallback")
                        //  Timber.d("onSuccess for connection")
                        eventBusManager?.post(
                            EventBusManager.MessageEvent(
                                EventBusConstants.MQTT_CONNECTED
                            )
                        )
                        subscribeToReportedTopic()
                        subscribeToLoadedDevicesReportedChannel()
                    }

                    override fun onFailure(asyncActionToken: IMqttToken, exception: Throwable?) {
                        // Something went wrong e.g. connection timeout or firewall problems
                        Timber.e("qq - onFailure for connection :: token.actionCallback - " + exception.toString())
                        eventBusManager?.post(
                            EventBusManager.MessageEvent(
                                EventBusConstants.MQTT_NOT_CONNECTED
                            )
                        )
                        exception?.printStackTrace()
//                    connectToMQTTServer()
                    }
                }

            }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            eventBusManager?.post(
                EventBusManager.MessageEvent(
                    EventBusConstants.MQTT_NOT_CONNECTED
                )
            )
            Timber.e("qq - Error occurred while connecting MQTT Client, Error = " + e.toString())
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi Hamza, welcome to the forum. It will be of great help for others to understand the problem if you can share a sample or the current code

Comment: i have updated my question with code block of connecting to my mqtt broker.

Comment: Can you edit the question to try and expand the description of the problem please. The error implies that at the time of the failure the android device was not connected to any network, in which case there is nothing that can be done apart from register a broadcast listener to be notified when the device reconnects before trying to open a new connection to the broker

Comment: i already have a listener which detects the internet connection and i am triggering the new connection when internet is available. but i am unable to understand why i am getting the socketException. actucally i am connecting my device with android phone through TCP client (socket) and then send wifi to my IOT device after sending wifi i am closing the socket connection it is due to that ??? @hardillb